# How to call an API, based on some variables in a client component, in Next js 13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a list of products that I can get in my site using a simple function inside a server component.

```
async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch(`${apiPath}`);
    const data = (await res.json()) as PackProps[];
    return data
}
```

The user of the site can apply some filters to the list. I already got the new API format that I have to call with the right new parameters, but I don't now how to call it.

The issue is that the filter selection is written inside a client component, which is separated from the component that has the role to show the list.

If i try to nest the components and to pass the parameters I need, then I have another problem:

```
... cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'Promise<Element>' is not a valid JSX element.
```

Of course, I cannot call an API and mark my function component as async, inside a client component.

Can you give me some hints on how can I manage to call an API (or maybe force an api to re-render), without losing the benefits of Server Side Rendering?

Comment: Hey, It looks like you're trying to conditional render the component based on a promise.
On the component return instead of this, try to assign a state variable to hold the data that is going to be fetched, and do something like `return fetchedData ? fetchedData : null` fetch the data in the useEffect and that should do the trick

Comment: Thank you for the response, but actually, that's quite the opposite. I need to compose a specific API, based on some variables that i can get only after the interaction with a user, in a client component. Once i get the informations i need, I don't know how to call the API inside the client component, due to the fact that i cannot append the async keyword in a client environment

Comment: This blog explains everything in great detail - https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/

Comment: Thank you, axios and useEffect hook made the work!

Answer (score 0):

And still, how did you triggered that from client component as you cannot pass a function as props to it?